# Rendering user vote count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm using this gem for comments: https://github.com/lml/commontator

Which is setup to easily plug into this gem to vote on the comments: https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable

Everything seems to be working fine. But when trying to calculate a users total votes (the total votes received on all comments by the user) (karma)

```
<%= @user.votes.count %>
```

I get this error

```
undefined method `votes' for #<User:0x0000010dbf23a0>
```

So I tried this:

```
<%= @user.comments.map{|c| c.votes.count}.inject(:+) %>
```

Which resulted in another error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: commontator_comments.commontator_id: SELECT "commontator_comments".* FROM "commontator_comments"  WHERE "commontator_comments"."commontator_id" = ? AND "commontator_comments"."commontator_type" = ?
```

How do I render the total number of votes received on all comments by a particular user?

Comment: Did you try `@user.find_voted_items.count` or `@user.get_voted(Comment).count` ?

Comment: Yup, both give me a NoMethodError

Comment: did you add `acts_as_voter` to user model?

Comment: Great! just did that, now when using @user.find_voted_items.count it gives me the number of items the user voted on. I'm trying to yield the total vote count the user has received.

Comment: For example if the user commented twice and received 4 votes on one comment and 2 on the other, his vote count is 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have this setup

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
  acts_as_commentator
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_votable
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And the following after installing `commentator` and `acts_as_votable` gems

```
rails generate acts_as_votable:migration
rake commontator:install
rake db:migrate
```

You should be able to get the number of votes like this

```
@user.comments.collect{|c| c.votes.size}.inject(:+)
```

Comment: Now i'm getting "Could not find table 'comments'"

Comment: I really appreciate your responses and effort, I'm just not sure why getting the vote count is coming to be impossible.